# Encrypt Images in Android to send to a PHP server

Tags: php, android, encryption, aes

**What I have:**
I have some images on SDcard, to be sent to a PHP server.

**What I want:**
I want to encrypt these images before sending to server. There will be a unique key, for every user of application, which will be used for encryption on Android Side and for decryption on PHP server side.

Please guide me how can I do this encryption and how should I send these encrypted Images to server. I can send simple images to a server (using multipart etc). But what should be the way to encrypt and then send the image to server?

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html

Comment: Down vote, just because you can't understand a simple question? I think Waqas replied below with something very simple & helpful, that I was expecting. Oh, BTW your GENERIC LIST of possible reasons is not much helpful. Can you please point out the reason for this down vote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can write you some simple steps to achieve this:

1. Convert your image into bytes array. Read [this](http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-development-answers-tutorials-code-snippets/2189-image-file-png-jpg-byte-array-viceverca.html)
2. Convert that bytes array into Base64 string. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)
3. Encrypt Base64 string using [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings) sample code
4. Send the encrypted string to your server using ksoap or json

**If you reverse this process on server, you'll get your image back.*
Tadaaa!  :)

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I'll try that for sure.

Comment: Don't convert to base64 and then encrypt. Encrypt the `byte[]` array, then base64 encode the cipher only if you can't store `byte[]` directly.

Comment: yes, thats also one way to do it. but i personally like to play with strings rather than bytes  :)